# Does 'skittish' derive from the noun 'skite'?

Tags: derivation

A skittish pony is one that is characterised by unpredictable, unstable behaviour, usually because of nervousness. A skittish investor is one that is over-cautious or who quickly pulls out of a trade or deal. [Merriam Webster.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skittish)

The common denominator appears to me to be the unreliable characteristic of man or beast, resulting in unpredictable behaviour.

There is a noun, skite, with an accompanying verb, which [the OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/181042?rskey=806Gtj&result=1#eid) lists as part of Scottish and 'Northern' dialect.

'On the skite' is Scottish for being drunk. 'A skite' is a ricochet or a glancing blow.

I wonder if the unreliable nature of an inebriated person or a sideways blow or a glancing ricochet indicates that 'skittish' originates with 'skite'.

The vulgar verb 'skite', to defecate, is very obscure and the Australian/New Zealand meaning of 'skite' - 'boastfulness or conceit' seems to be unrelated, but the Scottish use of 'skite' or 'skyte' as someone who babbles or 'blethers' without logic or consequence may also have a bearing. [All from OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/181042?rskey=806Gtj&result=1#eid)

Does 'skittish' derive from 'skite' ?

Answer (score 2):

The two terms appear to have in common the Scandinavian root ***skyt-*** meaning “to shoot or move quickly”. Skite however is a more recent term than skittish.

[Skittish:](https://www.etymonline.com/word/skittish)

> early 15c., "very lively, frivolous," ***perhaps from Scandinavian base *skyt- (stem of Old Norse skjota "to shoot, launch, move quickly")***, from PIE root *skeud- "to shoot, chase, throw." ***Sense of "shy, nervous, apt to run" first recorded c. 1500, of horses.***

[Skite:](https://www.etymonline.com/word/skite#etymonline_v_38100)

> “contemptible person," 1790, Scottish and Northern, earlier "sudden stroke or blow" (1785), ***perhaps from Old Norse skyt-, from skjota "to shoot"*** (see shoot (v.)). Old Norse skita "to shit" might have had some influence on the sense of the English word.